# "\r" and "\r\n" is transformed into "\n" in inner HTML

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

When I am trying to insert a string with `"\r"` into a inner HTML of an element, I realized that the value is changed.

```
var elem = document.createElement("textbox"),
    value = "\r HI \r\n\n";

elem.innerHTML = value;

var str = JSON.stringify(elem.innerHTML);

console.log(str);
// output: "\n HI \n\n"
```

This same thing happens to other HTML elements too.

1. May I know what is happening here?
2. And why `"\r\n\n"` is not converted to `"\n\n\n"` but `\n\n`?

Comment: `\r\n` (Windows format), `\r` (old Mac format) and `\n` (Linux format) are all normalised to `\n`.

Comment: Why do you *JSON.stringify* text?

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol—do you have a reference?

Comment: @RobG Just to display the changed string

Comment: For your question 2, `\r\n` is a _single_ Windows-style newline, not two newlines.